# Check if questions can be assigned

Tags: algorithm

An exam is to be conducted. N students will give the exam.

Students are numbered as 1, 2, 3 . . N. There are M questions and each student should be asked to only one of those M questions.

The questions are numbered as 1, 2, 3 . . M. The conditions are that:

```
1. ith question should be asked to exactly Ai students
2. No two consecutively numbered students get the same question to solve.
```

Given numbers N, M and array Ai, I need to find out if the questions can be assigned to students as per the given conditions.

Note : summation Ai will be equal to N.

Example : Let M=3 and N=7 and array be [3 3 1] Then here answer will be YES.

How to solve this problem ?Please help

Comment: Which part of the exercise are you having trouble with?

Comment: Two hints :- 1. `N=1+2+3+...+M=M(M+1)/2` and 2.Try searching about `deragements`.This question is related to combinatorics!

Comment: @shekharsuman How please elaborate ?

Comment: @user3804397-This is for you today! If you're unable to solve it,I'll surely help tomorrow!BTW,which part you're unable to understand? Also,I am gonna sleep now...

Comment: @shekharsuman How are you relating it with dearrangment.And ok..I will work on it today..Hope i get it..

Comment: @user3804397-Probably,I am sleepy now.Really,it has got nothing to do with deragements! SORRY,but,I promise to help you tomorrow,you try your best today. Also,if solved,please leave me a message! BEST WISHES FROM MY SIDE...

Comment: @shekharsuman Hey i solved..:).Just a basic condition to check

Comment: oh you just solved it... I'm a bit too late :P

Comment: @user3804397-That's why I left it for you. ***CONGRATS!***

Answer (score 0):

It's about to check if the largest element in `A` is bigger than `N / 2 + 1` because of **Pigeon Hole Principle**. When it's less than `N / 2 + 1`, we are able to assign every question to only odd numbered students, else we could not because at least 1 even numbered student will get this question, and result in a clash.